Reset device in xcode (Device>Erase all settings...) did not work
My virtual device freezed and I am not able to run it.
I tries to run in by button, I changed device type and I restarted whole xcode.
I tried Device>Erase All content and settings. But it did not worked.
https://ibb.co/d2FJY98
What can I do now?

Try deleting your simulator and reinstalling it this way:
Install and uninstall Simulator runtimes

I don´t see my device there.
